# Write to WebSphere clustered queue fails

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I have an C# service which reads messages from a WebSphere MQ queue using the .Net MQ interface library supplied by IBM, sends them to another application for processing and then writes the response to another queue.

When I connect to the response queue I have code of the form shown below (the MQ designers on site told me that I should always use the same handle for the response queue manager as the request queue manager)

The QueueName variable is set to the ReplyTo Queue name in the request message if present or a default if missing.

```
var ResponseQueueManager = RequestQueueManager;
var ResponseQueue = ResponseQueueManager.AccessQueue(QueueName,
    MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT, 
    ResponseQueueManager.Name, 
    null, 
    null);
```

This all works fine if the response queue name is not a clustered queue. However if I try to write to a clustered environment I get a UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME error thrown by the MQenvironment when I do the write, although I know the queue name is valid. Do I need to set additional attributes on the AccessQueue call?

I managed to read from a queue on the same queue manager OK so I don't understand why I write back to a queue under the same queue manager in a clustered environment.

Comment: UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME is because MQ is unable to resolve the response queue. The queue does not exist on the queue manager to which your application is connecting to. That queue might be existing on another queue manager in the cluster but it's not shared. So check your response queue definition.

Comment: If you open a clustered queue using both the queue name AND the queue manager name, MQ will only resolve the queue on that queue manager. If the clustered queue only exists on other queue managers, MQ won't resolve it. Try opening the queue without the queue manager name and MQ will resolve one of the instances that does exist based on the workload balancing policy you've configured.